# I need help for Google Map API

Tags: java, android, google-maps

yet I have another problem with my android app
I developed a pretty basic application that contains a single Activity and displays google maps (I used google maps API). The compilation ends with no errors, I also generate the apk without any problems but when I run my application on different devices only displays a blank page with the Google sign below this page.

```
[![This the screenshot of my application][1]][1]


package com.example.amine.bea_mapapp;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
   LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
  }
  }
```

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">My API key is here</string>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.amine.bea_mapapp">
<permission android:name="com.androidcom.example.amine.bea_mapapp.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.androidcom.example.amine.bea_mapapp.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.androidcom.example.amine.bea_mapapp.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSFREVICES"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="My API key is here" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Look in the logs for errors related to the api key

Comment: which apk file you generated.. ?  signed apk or debug apk..?

Answer (score 1):

Seems problem with your Google API keys. What key are you using at

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="My API key is here" />
```

If still struggling with issue, generate a new Google Map API keys with a keystore  generated from your machine and build apk with that new MAP API key. I am sure it will work in all devices  then.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to check **Google account** in that device is logged in or not
Second thing check **inbuilt map** in your testing device is working fine or not. Because google map access some services from device existing map application and your google account.?

Comment: Yes these things are mandatory for your map in android application.